# Multi Bit Logic Gate

Tags: verilog

I'm having trouble with this bit of code. I know that the problem is with the 7-bit output of my NAND and AND gate, but I don't know how to simplify it without making a separate gate for each bit. I'm also not sure what the anode_1_7 is for, or the buf statements. I was just told to include them.

```
module seven_segment_top(sw, btnc, btnl, btnr, segment, anode, anode_1_7);
    input [3:0] sw;
    input btnc, btnl, btnr, anode_1_7;
    output [7:0] segment, anode;
    wire lnot;

    seven_segment S0(sw[3:0], segment[6:0]);
    not(segment[7], btnc);

    nor(anode[0], btnl, btnr);
    nand(anode[7:1], btnl, 1'b1);
    not(lnot, btnl);
    and(anode[7:1], btnr, lnot);

    buf(anode[1],anode_1_7);
    buf(anode[2],anode_1_7);
    buf(anode[3],anode_1_7);
    buf(anode[4],anode_1_7);
    buf(anode[5],anode_1_7);
    buf(anode[6],anode_1_7);
    buf(anode[7],anode_1_7);
endmodule
```

Comment: Include a [mcve] - **what** is wrong with your code? Also, Verilog is 0-indexed - you should probably be using `0 - 6` instead of `1 - 7`.

Comment: Have you been forbidden from using behavioral Verilog for this assignment? Otherwise, you should be using `assign` statements instead of explicitly defining gates…

Comment: @hnefatl anode 0 follows different logic than 1-7, that's why 0 isn't included in the statements. And the problem is that I get an error saying "primitive output connection must be a scalar var or vet" for the lines corresponding to the NAND and AND statement.

Comment: @duskwuff Yeah, we can't use behavioral yet, only structural.

Comment: @toolic I mainly just want to know how to instance the NAND and AND gates I have with the 7 bit bus I've been given, because right now the fact that the output is multi-bit is causing an error.

Comment: Can you draw a schematic of the logic you're trying to create here?

Comment: @duskwuff I figured it out, thank you though for your suggestions! I guess I just had to replace the anode[7:1] in both my my gates with anode_1_7, and then just buf that value into the actual bits of anode, because they're all the same anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Two options:

1. Arrayed module instances. Not commonly used but is part if IEEE1364-1995. This approach works for simple iterations.

   ```
   nand nd[7:1] (anode[7:1], btnl, 1'b1);
   ```
2. Generate loop. Added in IEEE1364-2001 and commonly used. This approach is far more flexible and can be used for fancier compile/elaboration code expansion/slection.

   ```
   genvar gidx;
   generate
     for (gidx=1; gidx<8; gidx=gidx+1) begin : assign_anode
       nand(anode[gidx], btnl, 1'b1);
     end
   endgenerate
   ```